# How to plot a dataframe with 4 columns that need top be grouped in to just 2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

my data looks like

```
Fem_Applied <- c(10,15,10)
Fem_Success <- c(3,5,2)
Mal_Applied <- c(20,15,20)
Mal_Success <- c(4,3,3)
Role <- c("A","B","C")

df <- data.frame(Role,Fem_Applied,Fem_Success,Mal_Applied,Mal_Success)
```

And while I can plot it ok useing melt(df) and role as ID variables by default, I end up with 4 columns. What I want is two columns, one red for women and one blue for men. And the applied stacked on top of the successfull with applied alpha being lower

[image: I want something along these lines, but with two columns]

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you need `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -Role, names_to = c('.value', 'col'), names_sep = '_')` ?

Comment: Did the edit help? I cant expplain what I want  my data frame to look like just the plot, so one colour for each gender and different alphas to distinguish between applied and success, stacked together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

separate(melt(df), "variable", into = c("Gender", "Result"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(fillcat = paste(Gender, Result)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Gender, value, fill = fillcat)) +
  geom_col(aes(group = Result)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF3456", "#FF345680", "#3456FF", "#3456FF80")) +
  facet_grid(~Role, switch = "x") +
  labs(x = "Role", y = "Count") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"),
        legend.position = "none",
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: The example is great, but when I use it for my real data I cant get the columns to stack, any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Role) %>% 
  separate(name, c("Gender", "b"), convert = T) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Gender, y = value, fill = b)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

To have role wise plot you can use

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Role) %>% 
  separate(name, c("Gender", "b"), convert = T) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Gender, y = value, fill = b)) + 
  geom_col() + facet_wrap(Role~.)
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty close, but how would I make the graph look closer to the one I poosted? With applied and successful being the same colour and male female being different? So use different transperancy to distinguish